# how to refresh listview every 5 second help me

Tags: android

below is my code i want a every 5 second listview wil refresh with new values what do i do please check my code i just follow this simple tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/  now i want to update every 5 second when i  run this code app crash due to  may b notify inside runable tell me why?

```
public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

    Handler mHandler;
    static int n = 4;
    private static String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[n];

    MobileArrayAdapter setListAdapter ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MOBILE_OS[0] = "Android1";
        MOBILE_OS[1] = "iOS1";
        MOBILE_OS[2] = "WindowsMobile1";
        MOBILE_OS[3] = "Blackberry1";

        this.mHandler = new Handler();

        this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,5000);
        setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
    }

    private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            MOBILE_OS[0] = "hello1";
            MOBILE_OS[1] = "hello2";
            MOBILE_OS[2] = "hllo3";
            MOBILE_OS[3] = "hello4";
            Toast.makeText(ListMobileActivity.this, "in 
                    runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ListMobileActivity.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);
        }
    };//runnable

}

private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: try using Timer Class

Comment: problem on this line setListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  how to update listview inside runable??

Comment: just tell me how to set adapter inside runable ??

Comment: if i comment this line         setListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); then TOast message   Toast.makeText(ListMobileActivity.this,"in 
                          runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); will show every 5 second

Comment: how to refresh lisview with new array values evry 5 second?

Answer (score 0):

Using Timer Class you can update your ListView Every 5 sec As Follows:

```
public class ListViewRefreshEvery5Seconds extends ListActivity 
{
    Timer timer;
    ArrayList<String> arr1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            arr1.add("Item "+i);
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setTimerForAdvertise();
    }

    void setTimerForAdvertise() {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 5000, 5000);
    }

    public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask 
    {

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {

                            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
                            {
                                arr1.add("Item "+i);
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        }

    }
}
```

Or If you want to update ListView only once then you can simply use Handler like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
                {
                    arr1.add("Item "+i);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 5000);
```